# Javascript closure; is the return manatory?

Tags: javascript, closures

I try to learn this concept but I'm not sure regard the return.  Currently in the example that I saw (many of them are looking like following) this is closure, but I don't understand why I should return counter, its mandatory or otherwise its not closure?

```
function makeCounter() {
    var count = 0;
    function counter() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

like this

```
function makeCounter() {
    var count = 0;
    function counter() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }

}
```

update- makeCounter is still clousre

```
function makeCounter() {
    var count = 0;
    function counter() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }
    return counter;

    var count2 = 0;
    function counter2() {
        count2 = count2 + 1;
        return count2;
    }

}
```

Comment: In the second example, `counter()` is never called and `makeCounter()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: For completeness, you should show how you expect to use `makeCounter()` because that is relevant to whether your first example is going to do what you want it to do also.

Comment: @jfriend00-let say that makeCounter have additional code in it still it is clousre ? I must return the function with the "local varible " to become a clousre ?

Comment: If you look at how you're going to use `makeCounter()`, then it should be obvious that you have to return a function for it to have any hope of working.  And, yes in your cirumstance you do need to return an internal function in order to create a closure.

Comment: @jfriend00-Thanks,so makeCounter called clousre so if I have inside it counter1 and counter and just one of them return function still the makeCounter called clouser?

Comment: I don't follow your latest comment.  You would have to illustrate with actual code added to your question (code is not legible in comments).

Comment: In your update, `counter2()` is never called so it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific example, you have to return the local function `counter` in order to create a closure.

In your second code example, nothing is returned from `makeCounter()` so no closure is created.  In fact `makeCounter()` doesn't even do anything because `counter()` is never called.

If you look at how `makeCounter()` in your first example would be used, it would be like this:

```
var myCntr = makeCounter();
var firstCnt = myCntr();
var secondCnt = myCntr();
```

From just the expected usage alone, it should be obvious that `makeCounter()` has to return a function in order to be useful.

---

A closure in Javascript is created when some code continues to hold a reference to anything in a function scope, long after the function itself has finished its execution.  This can happen either by returning a local function from the function as in your first code example.  Or, it can happen when there is an asynchronous callback function or event handler that can be called some time in the future that is contained within the function.

---

So, in this example:

```
function makeCounter() {
    var count = 0;
    function counter() {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    }
    return counter;
}

var myCntr = makeCounter();
```

The myCntr variable which is still in scope and a live variable contains a reference to the internal `counter()` function which in turn contains a reference to the inner scope variables in `makeCounter()`.  This lasting reference to the inner scope is what tells the JS interpreter and garbage collector that the `makeCounter()` local scope cannot be garbage collected and will last.  This concept is called a closure.

A simplistic way of thinking about it that works well for me is to just think of it in terms of garbage collection.  In JS, a variable is eligible for garbage collection when there is no code that still has a reference to that variable and thus nothing can use that variable any more.  The same is true for function scopes.  If you think of a function scope like an object that gets garbage collected, then a function scope can be garbage collected only when there is no code that is still operating that still has a reference to it.  Returning an inner function and storing that return value into a variable creates such a reference to that inner scope so as long as that variable itself is still live, then the function scope cannot be garbage collected and will continue to be live.  This concept is called a closure.  It does not exist in all languages, but is a very useful feature in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The function `counter` is a local function to `makeCounter`. You can't call that function outwith the scope of `makeCounter`.

The return in `counter` returns the `count` value to the scope of `makeCounter`. So you need a return, like in the first example, to then return the value from `makeCounter`.